# PHP User Editable Form

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, user-input

I am trying to go into a database and get information.  Then put it into a form so the user can edit there information and then save it.

Here is my code on how I think I would do it.  I don't know what I am doing wrong.  How would I go about doing this for a drop down menu?

```
<?php
include("login_check.php");
include("dbconnect.php");
mysql_select_db("maxgee_close2");
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['maxgee_me_user']);
$result = mysql_query("select user_id from users where username = '$username'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);    
mysql_free_result($result);
$eventinfo =mysql_query("SELECT `event_id`, `user_id`, `event_name`, `event_category`, `event_description`, `event_admission`, `event_amount`, `event_start_date`, `event_end_date`, `event_location`, `event_family` FROM `events_main` WHERE `user_id`='{$row['user_id']}'") ;
?>
<form action="sendeventdata.php" method="post">
 Event Name:<input type="text" name="event_name" value="<?php echo '{$row['event_name']}';?>" />
```

Comment: In this line Event Name:<input type="text" name="event_name" value="<?php echo '{$row['event_name']}';?>" /> ... You need use $eventinfo['event_name']   some other problem?

Comment: @SomeKittens I am getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'

Answer (score 0):

You're `echo`ing the variable improperly.  It looks like you're copying a templating engine.

instead of:

```
<?php echo '{$row['event_name']}';?>
```

Use

```
<?php echo $eventinfo['event_name'];?>
```

You had three issues: the curly braces shouldn't be used like that (that's a template thing) and you had nested single quotes, which borks everything.  Finally, you were requesting `event_name` from the wrong array.

Comment: how would i replace/fix this?

Comment: Will that output the value in a form?

Comment: Can someone please explain why they're downvoting?

Comment: @SomeKittens Im not... but why wont $eventinfo['event_name'] echo?

Comment: can you post the results of `var_dump($eventinfo);`?